# Searching for a document in MongoDB by value of it's array - Mongoid/Sinatra

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongoid

I got document in Mongo

```
{
"_id": ObjectId("53638084e1054e706f000001"),
"name": "Vasya",
"order": [
  "burger",
  "nuggets",
  "mtdew"
  ],
}
```

Now I need to find it

```
get '/order/:order' do
  @clients = Client.where(order: [':order'])
  haml :index
end
```

But it returns nothing. Please help me with this action.

Comment: what is `:order` in your context?

Comment: @Sebastian _burger_ or _nuggets_ or _mtdew_ in this case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to find documents with a specific element in the `order` array:

```
db.orders.find({"order": "nuggets"})
```

In Ruby syntax it should be (untested):

```
get '/order/:order' do
  @clients = Client.where(order: params[:order])
  haml :index
end
```

Comment: Code for command line is works properly, but when I use your Ruby code it returns nothing again